# Change evaluation timeout in RubyMine debugger

Tags: remote-debugging, rubymine

I use RubyMine and its remote debugger. At a breakpoint I want to make an IMAP request so it take a long time. But I get an exception `"Timeout: evaluation took longer than 10 seconds."` 
I tried to increase debug connection timeout in Settings->Debugger. But obviously this trick didn't work.

So is it possible to increase evaluation expresion timeout in RubyMine debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was actually not in RubyMine debugger. So the question isn't correct. I've found that the reason of timeout was actual time out of a web-server worker. So the fix is in changing worker timeout. Currently, I'm using Puma, and for it the fix is next (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43166847/1771495)):

```
# config/puma.rb    
if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'development'
  worker_timeout 3600
end
```

Answer (score 16):

You can change it.  Open up Preferences and under `Build, Execution, Deployment`, select `Debugger`.  From there, there is an option `Debug connection timeout (s)`.  Change that value.  Or just search for `Debug connection timeout and it should show up highlighted.

Comment: As it is written in my question I've already done this but it did'n help my much.

Answer (score -1):

For those who still looking for an answer, check `client.timeout` setting. I had the same problem with `client.timeout = 240` but works for me with `client.timeout = 60`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Where can I change this setting?

Comment: I have this setting in my hooks file. By default it should be 60 if not specified another value.

Comment: Ai I right that you change it in file hooks.rb? If this is right it's not works for me as I don't have such file in my project. Sorry if I'm saying something stupid right now. It seems to me that I don't understand right now something very simple in you answer.