# Puma Rails 5 binding.pry only available for 60 seconds before timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, pry

Puma times out my request when I'm using `binding.pry`. In my controller

```
def new
  require 'pry'
  binding.pry
end
```

I then make a request that hits the controller and enter the pry session. After 60 seconds Puma? times out my request, restarts a worker and subsequently blows up by debugging session.

```
[1] pry(#<Agent::ClientsController>)> [3522] ! Terminating timed out worker: 3566
[3522] - Worker 0 (pid: 4171) booted, phase: 0
```

I generated this app with suspenders if that matters. How do I extend my debugging session in rails 5?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about this?

```
# config/puma.rb    
...

environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

...

if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'development'
  worker_timeout 3600
end
```

---

*Edit (Rails 5.1.5):*

Because ENV['RACK_ENV'] was empty, I did the following:

```
# config/puma.rb 

...

if ENV.fetch('RAILS_ENV') == 'development'
   puts "LOGGER: development => worker_timeout 3600"
   worker_timeout 3600
end
```

Answer (score 8):

You can create a configuration file and set the timeout value in there (for all requests, not just ones involved in debugging).  I'd recommend making a dev-specific one, and referencing that when running the server locally (and not setting some big timeout value for production).

In your rails application, create a file like `/config/dev_puma_config.rb` and in it put:

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma

worker_timeout 3600
```

Then when you start your server, reference that file with a `-C` like this:

`bundle exec puma -t 1:1 -w 1 -p 3000 -e development -C config/dev_puma_config.rb`

As a bit of background info on that worker_timeout setting, here's what the puma config says about it:

> Verifies that all workers have checked in to the master process within
>   the given timeout. If not the worker process will be restarted. This
>   is not a request timeout, it is to protect against a hung or dead
>   process. Setting this value will not protect against slow requests.
>   Default value is 60 seconds.